# I want to learn the basics for developing libraries for arduino, could someone please suggest the document where i can get the details.

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

I wanted to integrate a sensor to arduino uno. It may be any sensor, but I should design the drivers and libraries myself. I am a beginner to this stuff. Please could someone suggest me how to start this.

For example: I have a arduino uno and a accelerometer sensor(adxl345). How should I start integrate the sensor to arduino, what are the basics I should know before doing this and what details I should know before starting. And how do I start after having those details.

Please suggest me on this or guide me the location where I get these details.

Answer (score 2):

To write Arduino libraries, here are two tutorials I recommend:

- [Writing a Library for Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial)
- [Classes Course on Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

Once you know how to write libraries and classes, you might want to go further.

I'm developing a spherical robotic smart toy for children with autism using Arduino, and I had the same issue as you: how can I write or use libraries to keep my code clean and make it reusable.

The first thing I did was to left the Arduino IDE because I think it lacks the basic function a real programmer needs such as error checking and code completion (you could argue that it checks your code while compiling, but I want real time error checking).

I also needed a way to compile my code without using the old `avr-gcc` provided by the Arduino IDE. That's where [Sudar's Arduino-Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) came as a blessing! I could write my code using my favorite text editor and compile it simply.

To help some friend with their project, I put up a [Bare-Arduino-Project](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project), with all the documentation you need to get up and running.

Of course it is just a `framework` to get you started, but you can configure everything to suit your need. It will work on OS X and Linux. It should work on Windows as well with some changes but I haven't tested it.

Hope it helps! :)